# Redux best practice

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a doubt: in my project we are dispatching actions for every single click in every single component, and it takes so much efforts (actions,effects,reducers,selectors,facade,test)
Is it a good way to use everywhere or I might use only for the global state?
Inside the components we can pass nd retrieve parameters with inputs and outputs, do you consider a good practice use redux everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SHARI as a guideline to decide what has to be in the store and what not.

S: Shared, data across multiple components/services

H: Hydrated, if you want to save and reload the current state

A: Available, you don't want to fetch the same data more than once

R: Retrieved, data that is retrieved with a side effect

I: Impacted, data that can be impacted by other components/services